# Is "in his father's beautiful car" an adverbial of manner or an adverbial of place? What's the meaning of it?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Usually John is taken to school ***in his father's beautiful car.***

Is "in his father's beautiful car" an adverbial of manner or an adverbial of place? How to judge them?

Comment: Neither. If you need a category it is an adverbial of *means*.

Comment: @StoneyB How can you judge it is an adverbial of means? Can you describe the scene of this sentence?

Comment: The phrase does not signify that John is inside the car (though he no doubt is) or that he is conveyed in an automotive "manner" but that the car is the vehicle by means of which he is conveyed.

Comment: May I ask why it is important to classify this use? If we know what you're trying to accomplish with the classification we  may be able to provide you a better answer.

Comment: @StoneyB If we don't classify this use, it's not easy for us to figure out the meaning of the sentence. Now I am trying to analyze this kind of sentence structure in order to figure out the sentences alike.

Comment: @StoneyB I am still confused about the usage of the preposition. When we want to use an adverbial of means, how to distinguish the difference between "in", "with" and "by"?

Comment: Most prepositions have too many uses to be useful for these classifications. And meaning determines the classification; you can't classify the phrase unless you already know what it means. That's why the classifications are basically useless to the learner.

Comment: @StoneyB Because most prepositions have too many uses, if i don't analyze the sentence structure properly, how can I figure out the exact meaning of the preposition among its many meanings? Do you have a good suggestion?

Comment: You have to infer the meaning from context. You can make a shrewd guess from the meanings of the preposition you know already, or by looking up the components of the phrase. Some prepositions have fairly narrow meanings - *during*, for instance - but prepositions like *to*, *in*, *for* may express a wide varieties of meanings, such as purpose, direction, distance, means, manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phrase is not an adverbial of manner—replacing it with such an adverbial signifies an entirely different category of meaning:

> John is taken to school swiftly.
>   John is taken to school regularly.

Likewise, it is not an adverbial of place:

> John is taken to school in Paris.
>   John is taken to school across town.

It is an adverbial of *means*, naming the vehicle by which John is conveyed.

> John is taken to school by car.
>   John is taken to school by helicopter.

Note that *by*, which we ordinarily use with ‘modes’ of transportation, cannot be used here, because *by* with a ***specific*** entity implies agency— the entity is taken to be animate and capable of purposeful action:

> John is taken to school by his father.
>   John is taken to school by the Transport Authority.

Comment: what't the difference between "adverbial of manner" and "adverbial of means"?

Comment: @user48070 'Manner' ascribes a quality to the action. 'Means' designates a tool or technique employed in the action.